# Web Scraping - I need to login LinkedIn in order to webscrape (scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, linkedin-api

I am currently creating a web scraper for Linkedin but LinkedIn blocks my bot from scraping data because i am not logged in into any account. My goal is basically to scrape any job offering made by companies but my question is primarly on the logging in aspect of the code.

I am on Python 3.X using scrapy and formrequest.

I therefore looked online for the solution the formrequest package seemed to be the answer i needed. However, after several attempts it's still not working.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from ..items import LinkedinItem


class LinkedinSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'linkedin_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.css('form input::attr(value)').extract_first()
        print(token)
        return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            'csrf_token': token,
            'username': 'XXX@gmail.com',
            'password': 'XXX'
        }, callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
        items = LinkedinItem()
        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            Job_offers = response.css('.disabled').css('::text').extract()
            company = response.css('.job-card-search__company-name-link').css('::text').extract()
            information = response.css('.job-card-search__description-snippet').css('::text').extract()

            items['Job_offers'] = Job_offers
            items['company'] = company
            items['information'] = information

            yield items
```

I added the open_in_browser package in order to verify if i was logged in properly and the browser opens to the login screen and it's wrritten: please enter an email adress

I expect my browser to open to the home page with my account logged in.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

While I can't provide an answer to your original question, I can tell you that what you're doing is against [LinkedIn's software extensions policy](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibited-software-and-extensions?lang=en).

> In order to protect our members' data and our website, we don't permit the use of any third party software, including "crawlers", bots, browser plug-ins, or browser extensions (also called "add-ons"), that scrapes, modifies the appearance of, or automates activity on LinkedIn's website.

Be careful here. Not only do many websites employ methods to protect against scraping data, but some (LinkedIn included) have been to known to take developers to court over this kind of thing.

For a safe, legal way to do what you're trying to do, check out [LinkedIn's API page](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/).

Comment: Thank you, i am following a youtube guide as i am currently learning and this is purely for learning purposes. However i'll not take any risks and try the scraping on another website. Thanks for the information

Comment: Yeah, Linkedin is not the best place to learn web scraping :/  https://techcrunch.com/2016/08/15/linkedin-sues-scrapers/.

stackoverflow.com/jobs is a better option, however, it can ban your spider if you request too much.

Comment: What about this:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/emmawoollacott/2019/09/10/linkedin-data-scraping-ruled-legal/#3f79d74e1b54

Comment: Scraping Linkedin has been officially ruled legal, user data is not owned by Linkedin.